# R tools with tm packages

Tags: r, tm

I got this problem when I run this R code

```
x = read.csv("data2.csv", header = TRUE)
library(tm)
a <-Corpus(DataframeSource(x), readerControl = list(language="english"))
a <- tm_map(a, as.PlainTextDocument)

<simpleError in UseMethod("as.PlainTextDocument", x): 
   no applicable method for 'as.PlainTextDocument' applied 
   to an object of class "c('PlainTextDocument', 'TextDocument', 'character')">
```

I have installed the `SnowballC` packages, and I run R under ubuntu.
The data2.csv is a file contains lines of Strings.

Comment: Provide sample of data2.csv file....

Comment: The error is clear. You try to coerce a `PlainTextDocument`(ie , the same type) to a `PlainTextDocument`. Why?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `a <- tm_map(a, as.PlainTextDocument)` to do? As the `tm_map` help page points out, all the valid functions you can run with `tm_map` can be listed with `getTransformations()` and `as.PlainTextDocument` is not one of them. I would guess `class(a[[1]])` already returns "PlainTextDocument"